# How to connect Esper CEP engine with DDS

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, data-distribution-service, epl, opendds

I belive I am missing something related with dds concept. My idea is  to use a EsperIO adapter, data flow or plug-in to insert incomming events from dds to a esper engine, but I can't see it clear.

Somebody help!! (Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step by step would be 
1) receive event data from DDS i.e. Java DataReader
2) build an event object that Esper can understand; for this use a JavaBean-style class for example
3) send event object into Esper

There is no need to build an adapter or use EsperIO. The API to feed events into Esper is really simple. For API code see http://www.espertech.com/esper/longer-case-study/ or Esper docs.

Comment: Thanks so much, Im going to try your solution and comment the feeeback.

Comment: That`s for every one. Is any example implemented??

Comment: Examples are part of the Esper zip or jar file that you can download

Comment: Thanks so much we are going to develop a Java API for this purpose.